# Easy install is not recognized

Tags: python-2.7, easy-install

I installed easy install it is in my scripts folder. I set my path variable. When I type python in cmd it works, but no matter what I try if I type easy_install it says it is not recognized. I am trying to install pip and then pytmx. is there an easier way to install pytmx? or can someone please walk me through this so I can get this working.

new variable PY_HOME value C:\Python27
path variable %PY_HOME%;%PY_HOME%\Lib;%PY_HOME%\DLLs;%PY_HOME%\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Python27\scripts 
python version 2.7.8
windows 7 professional

Update uninstalled all versions of python reinstalled version 2.7.9
now pip is not a recognized command python is still recognized and give me a version number. I still cannot install pytmx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I needed to cd c:\python27\scripts, then use the pip install tmx command. Nothing I read anywhere suggested I had to run cmd from the directory that pip was in.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, as the scripts directory is clearly in your path.

Answer (score 0):

If you install python 2.7.9 pip is included.

Then just `pip install pytmx`